# Xamarin ImageView inherited class can't call getContext

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, imageview, android-context

```

```
public class MyImageView : ImageView
{
```

...

```
    public override void SetImageResource(int resId)
    {
        var inputBitmap = ProcessImage(ContextCompat.GetDrawable(getContext(), resId));
    }
```

...

```
}
```

```

during compile time getting error:

    `Controls/MyImageView.cs(...): error CS0103: The name 'getContext' does not exist in the current context`

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xamarin/C# normalization would be a read-only property named: `Context`

```
public override void SetImageResource(int resId)
{
    var inputBitmap = ProcessImage(ContextCompat.GetDrawable(Context, resId));
}
```